# Calculate running sum over 4-quarter period in SQL

Tags: sql

Two questions:

(1) I am looking at quarterly bank data and would like to calculate a running sum of, say, net income over the previous 4 quarters. For Bank A below, summing net income for 1Q2013-4Q2013 would total 177 (seen in 12M Net Income in 4Q2013 for Bank A).

(2) Also, I would like to calculate year-over-year income growth. For Bank A below, the 12m running net income in 2014 (246) would be 39% greater than a year earlier (the 12m running net income in 2013 was 177).

Your help is much appreciated!

```
Quarter Bank Name Net Income 12M Net Income YoY Income Growth
1Q2013 A 12 NA NA

2Q2013 A 56 NA NA

3Q2013 A 34 NA NA

4Q2013 A 75 177 NA

1Q2014 A 54 219 NA

2Q2014 A 123 286 NA

3Q2014 A 46 298 NA

4Q2014 A 23 246 39

1Q2015 A 72 264 21

2Q2015 A 34 175 -39

3Q2015 A 65 194 -35

1Q2013 B 32 NA NA

2Q2013 B 46 NA NA

3Q2013 B 57 NA NA

4Q2013 B 23 158 NA

1Q2014 B 56 182 NA

2Q2014 B 73 209 NA

3Q2014 B 24 176 NA

4Q2014 B 44 197 25

1Q2015 B 72 213 17

2Q2015 B 243 383 83

3Q2015 B 41 400 127
```

Comment: what version of SQL.  It appears to me that `Group by Grouping sets` may accomplish what your after if we can parse out year and quarters and if the RDBMS you're using supports it.  [SQLServer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510427%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) or maybe `with rollup` in [mySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-modifiers.html)  for your first part.  and perhaps using analytic `over partition by` for the second set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be able to sequence the values in the **Quarter** column correctly. Let's say you have functions YEAR() and QTR() that get the year and the quarter, respectively.

Then, to get a running sum of income over the previous 4 quarters, you would query:

```
SELECT [Bank Name], Quarter,
        SUM([Net Income 12M]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Bank Name]
                                   ORDER BY YEAR(Quarter), QTR(Quarter)
                                   ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS SumInc4Q
    FROM BankIncome
    ORDER BY [Bank Name], Quarter;
```

The ability to follow an aggregate function with an OVER clause is available in SQL Server 2005 and later, and I also found it in the ORACLE 10g documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much! QTR isn't a function in my version of SQL, but MONTH serves the same function.

Comment: Can anyone please help with the look-back question? Specifically, if I'm trying to find the YoY change, I want to look back at the 12m net income 4 quarters earlier. Thank you!